# Localization in a databound ComboBox isn't working correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, converters

I want to translate items of my combo box.
So I use a personalized converter KeyToTranslationConverter which convert an Enum value to a translated string.

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(string))]
public class KeyToTranslationConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
                                  object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return LocalizationResourcesManager.GetTranslatedText(value);
    }
}
```

My combo box is bound to the observable collection LanguagesEntries and the selectItem is bound to LanguageEntry attribute.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding LanguageEntries}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding LanguageEntry}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource Converter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

My problem is:
When the user change the language the method is called :

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.LanguageEntries).Refresh();
```

All items collections are translated except the selected item which is duplicated :

For example the selected item "Anglais" is not translated but the word English is in the combo box list.

Can someone help me.

Arnaud.

Comment: Simple solution:  instead of using a converter, expose a LocalizedName property on your model and bind to that.

Comment: For sure, your solution works. I want to use a converter because my view model has a lot of enum collections and so your solution ask too much time. I think my view model is easier to use if it contains no translation code.

Comment: Bind the SelectedItem property to a property of the view model, and when you change the language - refresh the bound selected property.

Comment: After refresh the view, I set the selected property with the enum value and send PropertyChangedEventHandler event. The IHM get the property but the converter is not called, And the old translated value is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem, I solved it by binding the converter to the itemssource instead of the itemtemplate.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding LanguageEntries, Converter={StaticResource LanguageEntriesConverter}}">
```

And the convert need to handle the collection instead of each item:

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value is System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<string>)
        {
            foreach (var c in (System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<string>)value)
            {
                c = LocalizationResourcesManager.GetTranslatedText(c);
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
```

The converter is called every time you update your itemssource either by assigning it to a new value or calling OnPropertyChanged.